# CSS Triangle inside a triangle?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a border like effect for the triangle. I have tried giving it a border, box shadow, neither works. Then if you do put another triangle div inside of it the outer triangle just becomes larger.

```
#triangle {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 25px 50px 25px 0;
  border-color: transparent #000 transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a pseudo-element like `:after`.

Here you go!

```css
#triangle {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 25px 50px 25px 0;
  border-color: transparent #000 transparent transparent;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#triangle:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 13px 25px 13px 0;
  border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;
  width: 0;
  top: -13px;
  left: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle">
</div>
```